# Using colnames() for xlab argument in ggplot2 returns NAs when using lapply

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, data-visualization, lapply

I am trying to create a function that plots multiple columns in a dataframe (36 in total) using the following function:

```
big5p1 <- function(i) {
        ggplot(big5_pos, aes(x= i, y = title)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5) +
        xlab(colnames(big5_pos)[i]) + #Issues with NAs
        ylab("Position") +
        geom_vline(xintercept = mean(i), color="red")
  }

lapply(big5_pos[2:3], big5p1)
```

When I check `colnames(big5_pos[2:36])` I do get a correct list of character names for each column. However, when using apply only some of the xlabs are printed correctly, and the rest just have NA as the label. Not sure what I am overlooking but any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to accept column name.

```
library(ggplot2)

big5p1 <- function(i) {
  ggplot(big5_pos, aes(x = .data[[i]], y = title)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5) +
    xlab(i) + 
    ylab("Position") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = mean(big5_pos[[i]], na.rm = TRUE), color="red")
}

result <- lapply(names(big5_pos)[2:3], big5p1)
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the x labels but now the xintercept for the mean is not showing up.

geom_vline(xintercept = mean(.data[[i]]), color="red")

Answer (score 0):

We could convert the column names to `sym`bols and evaluate with (`!!`)

```
library(ggplot2) 
big5p1 <- function(nm) {
  ggplot(big5_pos, aes(x =  !! rlang::sym(nm), y = title)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
   xlab(nm) + 
   ylab("Position") +
   geom_vline(xintercept = mean(big5_pos[[nm]], na.rm = TRUE), color="red")
   }
```

and then loop over the column names

```
result <- lapply(names(big5_pos)[2:3], big5p1)
```